# How to Programmatically Handle BLE Peripheral Removing Pairing from iOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

With an iOS app running in Central mode, and a BLE peripheral (e.g. the BLE113) with encrypted GATT characteristics - when the iOS app scans for and connects to the peripheral, it will automatically request a pairing when it discovers encrypted GATT characteristics.

If the iOS device and BLE peripheral each stay paired, everything is fine.

However, how does one handle the case where the BLE peripheral removes all of it's bonding information internally, without informing the iOS device that it's deleting the pairing keys?

iOS CoreBluetooth commands will just fail.

Is there anything that can be done programmatically to fix this problem? Either re-request a pairing, or unpair the iOS side?

iOS is pretty restricted with Bluetooth - so I can't see much of a good solution, other than to detect when writes fail, and ask the user to unpair manually (which is lame)

Comment: You are right, the user needs to delete the pairing/bonding from the Bluetooth settings screen in iOS.  There is nothing an app can do.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thannks. Are there any associated docs or examples of this? Also, does CoreBluetooth return any indication somewhere that this might be the case?

Comment: unfortunately there are no other solutions, only to delegate the user. I have the same problem and I could not find any other solution!

Comment: @GeekRiky I was able to solve this problem the other day, and have posted my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this one, and it turns out, you don't even need to unpair!!!

I wrote about my experiences here:

http://www.sureshjoshi.com/embedded/bgscript-pairing-hell/ and here: http://community.silabs.com/t5/Wireless/Bonding-issues-with-BLE121/m-p/163221#M10850

Essentially, from the firmware side, you can re-request an encryption when the device discovers that the pairing doesn't occur immediately. For BGScript, here is the pertinent code:

```
event sm_bonding_fail(handle, result) 
# If bonding fails, handle it gracefully based on the following possible results:
# - 0x018B - Out of bonds (no space left, all 8 bonding slots taken)
# - 0x0205 - Authentication failure (shouldn't happen with "just works" mode, but might otherwise)
# - 0x0206 - Pin or key missing (probably local or remote device is missing the key, but not both)
# - 0x0301 - Passkey entry failed (also shouldn't happen in "just works" mode unless bonding is cancelled)
# - 0x0302 - OOB data not available (only occurs if OOB is required and not supported on both ends)
# - 0x0303 - Authentication requirements (I/O capabilities required but not supported)
# - 0x0304 - Confirm value failed (PIN entry/comparison attempted but failed)
# - 0x0305 - Pairing not supported (also occurs if bond info removed from remote device but not local module)
# - 0x0306 - Encryption key size (key size insufficient to meet security requirements)
# - 0x0307 - Command not supported (SMP command is not supported on this device)
# - 0x0308 - Unspecified reason (may occur if bond info is present remotely but not locally)
# - 0x0309 - Repeated attempts (too little time has elapsed since last pairing/security request)
# - 0x030A - Invalid parameters (bad parameters sent during pairing/bonding process)

# NOTE: The most common cases:
# - 0x018B, which means you ran out of space and must remove at least one bond in order to bond again
# - 0x0206, which typically means the pairing info was removed on the remote device but not locally
# - 0x0301, which typically means the user cancelled the pairing request or entered the wrong passkey
# - 0x0305, which is like 0x0206 but is often generated instead if the remote device is a smartphone
# - 0x0308, which typically means the pairing info was removed on the local device but not remotely
if result = $018b then
    # Only solved by removing bonds - requires the user to reset the bonds...
end if

if result = $0301 then
    # Usually solved simply by trying again
    # Seems to solve most problems on iOS
    # On Android, pairing rejected a few times if Android deleted pairing without informing device
    call sm_encrypt_start(0, 1)
end if

if result = $0305 || result = $0206 then
    # Remove local bonding info first, then the remote device needs to reconnect
    # If current_bond_handle is $ff, that means we don't have a bonding handle - so not much we can do
    if current_bond_handle != $ff then
        call sm_delete_bonding(current_bond_handle)
    end if

    # Sometimes takes a few tries
    call connection_disconnect(0)
end if

if result = $0308 then
    # Remove remote bonding info first, then the remote device needs to reconnect
    # Android can recover automatically, iOS cannot
    # Instead of disconnecting, just force a re-encryption... Usually works
    call sm_encrypt_start(0, 1)
end if
end
```